# How to delete the record from CosmosDB specific days back

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection `activities` it contains a field `activityDate` which contain date like `2017-02-24T19:04:18Z`

I want to delete all record from this collection which are older that `numberOfDays`.

I am performing this task by writing cosmosdb stored procedure

I try something like

```
var query = 'SELECT * FROM activities a WHERE a.activityDate > = "' + numberOfDays+ '"';
```

I am facing problem executing the query as it's not syntactically correct

Or there can be some another way of doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for my problem:

```
// SAMPLE STORED PROCEDURE
function deleteActivitiesBackDate(numberOfDays) {
  var context = getContext();
  var collection = context.getCollection();
  var link = collection.getSelfLink();
  var response = context.getResponse();

 //validate inputs
  if(!numberOfDays || (typeof numberOfDays != "string")){
    return errorResponse(400, (!numberOfDays) ? "numberOfDays is Undefined":"String type is expected for numberOfDays.");
  }

 var targetDate = new Date();

 targetDate.setDate(targetDate.getDate() - numberOfDays);
 console.log("targetDate is "+targetDate);


  var query = 'SELECT * FROM activities a WHERE a.activityDate < "' + targetDate+ '"';
  var run = collection.queryDocuments(link, query, {}, callback);
  function callback(err, docs) {
    if (err){
        return errorResponse(400, err.message);
    }
    if (docs.length > 0){
        deleteDoc(docs);
    }else {
        return errorResponse(400, "The document was not found.");
    }
  }

  if (!run) {
      return errorResponse(400, "The document could not be deleted.");
  }

  function deleteDoc(document) {
    var docDeleted = collection.deleteDocument(document._self, function(err, result){
        if (err){
            return errorResponse(400, err.message);
        }
        response.setBody(result);
    });

    if (!docDeleted) {
      return errorResponse(400, "The document could not be deleted.");
    }
  };

  function errorResponse(code,message){
    var errorObj = {};
    errorObj.code = code;
    errorObj.message = message;
    errorObj.date = getDateTime();
    return response.setBody(errorObj);
  } 

  function getDateTime(){
    var currentdate = new Date();
    var dateTime = currentdate.getFullYear() + "-" +(currentdate.getMonth()+1)+ "-" +     currentdate.getDate()+ " "  +currentdate.getHours()+":"+currentdate.getMinutes()+":"+currentdate.getSeconds();
      return dateTime;
    }
}
```

With that you also need to enable partitions to execute `(<,>,<=,>=,!=)`

so try:
[image: This]

also inside `custom` have following JSON

```
{
  "indexingMode": "consistent",
  "automatic": true,
  "includedPaths": [
    {
      "path": "/*",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "kind": "Range",
          "dataType": "String",
          "precision": -1
        },
        {
          "kind": "Range",
          "dataType": "Number",
          "precision": -1
        },
        {
          "kind": "Spatial",
          "dataType": "Point"
        },
        {
          "kind": "Spatial",
          "dataType": "Polygon"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "excludedPaths": []
}
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare `a.activityDate` to `today` minus `numberOfDays`. The easiest way to do the subtraction is to convert the ISO-8601 string into a Date object then add 1000*60*60*24*numberOfDays to it then convert it back into an ISO-8601 string using the methods in your Date object (`Date.toISOString()` in JavaScript, but your language may be different). There may be some way to use JavaScript expressions within a WHERE clause but I don't know of it. Even if there was, I wouldn't recommend it because doing so would make the query a full table scan. So, I recommend that you do this conversion and subtraction client-side to get a scalar string to put into your query clause.