# Delete Documents from Cosmos using Query without Partition Key Specification

Tags: javascript, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to create a stored procedure to delete documents in Cosmos Db by using a query. Once the query returns the documents, I would like all the documents to be deleted.

I tried using the script from [this website](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ec9aa862-0516-47af-badd-dad8a4789dd8/delete-multiple-docdb-documents-within-the-azure-portal?forum=AzureDocumentDB) but this requires putting one partition key. My Cosmos collection has a separate partition key per document so it will not work

This is an example of a query I would like to run

```
SELECT c.currentTime, c.pastTime 
FROM C 
WHERE c.currentTime < c.pastTime
```

If that satisfies, I would like to delete all the results from that query.

Is there a way create a stored proc or modify the one in the website provided so it loops through all the collection instead of specifying one partition key?

Comment: how can you have separate partition key per document?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44329936/1220550

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way create a stored proc or modify the one in the website
>   provided so it loops through all the collection instead of specifying
>   one partition key?

The quick answer is no,please see some official statements:

1.I answered similar cases before, they all want to avoid such partition key requirement when executing SP.However,it can't be avoided.

[Azure Cosmos DB asking for partition key for stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48798523/azure-cosmos-db-asking-for-partition-key-for-stored-procedure)

[Cosmos DB Stored procedure did not execute without PartitionKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044575/cosmos-db-stored-procedure-did-not-execute-without-partitionkey)

> If the collection the stored procedure is registered against is a
>   single-partition collection, then the transaction is scoped to all the
>   documents within the collection. If the collection is partitioned,
>   then stored procedures are executed in the transaction scope of a
>   single partition key. Each stored procedure execution must then
>   include a partition key value corresponding to the scope the
>   transaction must run under.

2.Above statement and link have been modified into below new [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#scope-of-a-transaction):

[image]

3.You could follow official suggestion to get an idea of Bulk Executor Lib SDK. I found `BulkDelete` feature in this [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-bulkexecutor-dotnet-getting-started/tree/master/BulkDeleteSample),please try it.