# Unable to query Azure Cosmosdb using stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb, server-side

I made a Cosmosdb database using sql core api, and made a container named collection1 in which I saved a simple json data
which is as follows
{
"id" : "1",
"group" : "a"
}
I made group as my partition key. Then added a stored procedure and executed the default stored procedure, but I didn't get my json data as result, instead I got " no docs found"

Comment: what is the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I probably know your mistake, you have to define the partition key when you execute stored procedure because Cosmos DB SP demands that.(More details,you could refer to this thread:[Delete Documents from Cosmos using Query without Partition Key Specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58718052/delete-documents-from-cosmos-using-query-without-partition-key-specification/58722090#58722090))

[image]

If you didn't define any partition key, then it is identified as `empty`,the data which doesn't contain `group` column will be selected out.

Comment: I defined the partition key as /group but still no result.

Comment: @Shreyansh It should be `a`,the value of pk setting,not the name of pk.

Comment: @Shreyansh Can't figure out why you deleted the `thanks ,it worked` comment? What happened? Or you need further help? Any further questions, you could post here.

Comment: @Shreyansh If you think the answer is correct here, you could mark it which is beneficial for others.If you are not familiar with my words,please scan this SO rules:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work